# "Sequence full of colors" challenge on HackerRank

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

[This](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sequence-full-of-colors/problem) is the challenge:

> You are given a sequence of `N` balls in 4 colors: red, green, yellow and blue. The sequence is full of colors if and only if all of the following conditions are true:
>
> - There are as many red balls as green balls.
> - There are as many yellow balls as blue balls.
> - Difference between the number of red balls and green balls in every prefix of the sequence is at most 1.
> - Difference between the number of yellow balls and blue balls in every prefix of the sequence is at most 1.
> - Your task is to write a program, which for a given sequence prints True if it is full of colors, otherwise it prints False.

and this is my solution:

```hs
import Control.Monad (replicateM, foldM)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- getLine
  list <- replicateM (read n :: Int) getLine
  mapM_ (print . isgood) list

isgood :: String -> Bool
isgood = isValidFinal . foldM step (0,0)
  where
    step (x,y) c
      | c == 'R' = wrapValidInJust (x - 1, y)
      | c == 'G' = wrapValidInJust (x + 1, y)
      | c == 'Y' = wrapValidInJust (x, y - 1)
      | c == 'B' = wrapValidInJust (x, y + 1)
    isValid (x,y) = abs x <= 1 && abs y <= 1
    wrapValidInJust xy = if isValid xy then Just xy else Nothing
    isValidFinal (Just x) = x == (0,0)
    isValidFinal Nothing = False
```

I'm kind of happy with `main` and `isgood`, but the `step` function seems very hard to read.

Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

- `step` does two things: (1) step to the next state, and (2) check that the state is valid. Its name suggests only the first meaning. The repetition of `wrapValidInJust` suggests that they can be separated.
- Instead of `==` you can use pattern-matching.

```
isgood :: String -> Bool
isgood = isValidFinal . foldM (check . step) (0, 0)
  where

    step (x, y) 'R' = (x-1, y)
    step (x, y) 'G' = (x+1, y)
    step (x, y) 'Y' = (x, y-1)
    step (x, y) 'B' = (x, y+1)

    check (x, y) = if abs x <= 1 && abs y <= 1 then Just (x, y) else Nothing

    ...
```

Another reason `step` is hard to read is that you need to keep track of differences, which complexifies the meaning of `x` and `y`. You can just as easily count the four colors independently and compute the difference only in `check`. This is also the opportunity to use a record or a map to make the update syntax more uniform:

```hs
data RGBY = RGBY { r, g, b, y :: Int }

isgood :: String -> Bool
isgood = isValidFinal . foldM (check . step) (RGBY 0 0 0 0)
  where

    step x 'R' = x { r = r x + 1 }
    step x 'G' = x { g = g x + 1 }
    step x 'Y' = x { y = y x + 1 }
    step x 'B' = x { b = b x + 1 }

    check x = if abs (r x - g x) <= 1 && abs (y x - b x) <= 1
      then Just (x, y) else Nothing

    ...
```